# Probability that there exists $M>0$ such that two processes $\{X_t\}$ and $\{Y_t\}$ are smaller than $M$ at the same time, for infinitely many $t$.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Suppose I have two iid sequences of random variables $\{X_t\}_{t\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $\{Y_t\}_{t\in\mathbb{N}}$, both absolutely continuous with full support. I know that with probability one, for any $M>0$ we have that $|X_t|<M$ for infinitely many $t$ and thus 
$$
P(\liminf_{t\rightarrow\infty} |X_t| = \infty) = 0.
$$ 
The same is true for $\{Y_t\}$.

**Question:** Do we have
$$
P(\liminf_{t\rightarrow\infty} \,\, \max\{|X_t|,|Y_t|\} = \infty) = 0?
$$ 
That is, do we have with probability one that there exists a $M>0$ such that $|X_t|<M$ and $|Y_t|<M$ at the same time, for infinitely many $t$. The answer is unclear to me, because we cannot assume that $\{(X_t,Y_t)\}$ is an iid sequence in $\mathbb{R}^2$.